# Changing value of one Select2 from another creates recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have two Select2 elements. I want to change the value of one if the other one is changed. It creates recursion.

```js
$('.select2').select2().on('change.select2', function(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'select-1') {
        $('#select-2').val('all').trigger('change')
    } else if (e.target.id == 'select-2') {
        $('#select-1').val('all').trigger('change')
    }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-1" class="select2">
  <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>

</select>

<br><br>
<select id="select-2" class="select2">
  <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>

</select>
```

I changed the code to not trigger the change for the other element. But it still goes to recursion.

```js
let allowChange = true;
$('.select2').select2().on('change.select2', function(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'select-1') {
        if (allowChange) {
            $('#select-2').val('all').trigger('change')
            allowChange = false;
        } else {
            allowChange = true;
        }
    } else if (e.target.id == 'select-2') {
        if (allowChange) {
            $('#select-1').val('all').trigger('change')
            allowChange = false;
        } else {
            allowChange = true;
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-1" class="select2">
  <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>

</select>

<br><br>
<select id="select-2" class="select2">
  <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>

</select>
```

Is there a way to fix this and achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `.on('input'` to detect the current select2 change?

```js
$('.select2').select2().on('input', function(e) {
  console.clear();
  console.log('#' + e.target.id + ' value: ' + e.target.value);
  if (e.target.id == 'select-1') {
    $('#select-2').val('all').trigger('change')
  } else if (e.target.id == 'select-2') {
    $('#select-1').val('all').trigger('change')
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="select-1" class="select2">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>

</select>

<br><br>
<select id="select-2" class="select2">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. However, i'm using `Select2 4.0.6-rc.1` and this version doesn't seem to have the `on('input')` event. Any workaround for that?

Comment: [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) will work in the jquery `.on` event, select2 should detect this change.

Comment: I think the mentioned version doesn't trigger the event. Here's a fiddle for that https://jsfiddle.net/m19fg70a/

Answer (score 1):

```js
let allowChange = true;
$('.select2').select2().on('input', function(e) {
      if (e.target.id == 'select-1') {
        if (allowChange) {
            $('#select-2').val('all').trigger('change')
            allowChange = false;
        } else {
            allowChange = true;
        }
    } else if (e.target.id == 'select-2') {
        if (allowChange) {
            $('#select-1').val('all').trigger('change')
            allowChange = false;
        } else {
            allowChange = true;
        }
    }
    })
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-1" class="select2">
  <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>

</select>

<br><br>
<select id="select-2" class="select2">
  <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>

</select>
```

At First when you are attaching event using  **$('.select2').select2().on('change.select2', somefunction(){});**, it is finding all element with class .select2 which in your case are two dropdown tags and attaching event handler to all elements. **What is happening in your code is that when you invoke change of dropdown it calls handler and in handler you are calling change event programmatically so handlers are getting called recursively**. There are two ways to go around this. First you need to separate event binding and handler for dropdowns or you can just change event type which you are binding in using class selector.
I hope this helps you to understand the problem.